# Docker Compose env file priority over shell pass variables when they are not defined

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I define the same environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` using `environment` key (by not giving them a value) and also using `env_file` key, the first take priority even if it is not defined in the shell.

I'm using docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306

In the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) says:

> When you set the same environment variable in multiple files, here’s the priority used by Compose to choose which value to use:
>
> 1. Compose file
> 2. Shell environment variables
> 3. Environment file
> 4. Dockerfile
> 5. Variable is not defined

I assume that if the variable is not defined (point 5) in the shell it does not have priority over the variable defined in the environment file.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    env_file: "db-variables.env"
```

**db-variables.env**

```
POSTGRES_USER=bob
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

**Result:**

```
$ docker-compose run --entrypoint printenv db
Creating network "compose-example_default" with the default driver
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=105881c75c8c
TERM=xterm
LANG=en_US.utf8
PG_MAJOR=11
PG_VERSION=11.1
PG_SHA256=90815e812874831e9a4bf6e1136bf73bc2c5a0464ef142e2dfea40cda206db08
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
HOME=/root
```

I expect shell pass environment variables `environment` only take priority over `env_file` variables when they are really defined in the shell.

Have I misunderstood the documentation? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another section of the documentation on the environment variables I found [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file):

> Environment variables declared in the environment section override these values this holds true **even if those values are empty or undefined**.

RTFM to my self.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the doc:

> When you run the container, the environment variable defined in the Compose file takes precedence.

Define the variables to view as I think values are not set to the variables.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    env_file: "db-variables.env"
```

**db-variables.env**

```
POSTGRES_USER=bob
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

**Result:**

```
$ docker-compose run --entrypoint printenv db
Creating network "compose-example_default" with the default driver
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=8fcbf617bb6d
TERM=xterm
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
LANG=en_US.utf8
PG_MAJOR=11
PG_VERSION=11.3
PG_SHA256=2a85e082fc225944821dfd23990e32dfcd2284c19060864b0ad4ca537d30522d
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
HOME=/root
```

Comment: I know that if you value them, priority is given to those defined in the compose, my question is how to do so that if you do not assign value in the compose take the value defined the env_file.